# The jQuery ajax does not send more than two values to post url

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have the following code to send the data via Jquery AJAX and notice that I have three values that need to be sent to the receiving file(Addtocart.php).
The transmission and reception were good, but after a while I do not know why it no longer sends.. When one of the values is canceled and two remain, it sends.. but when three values are not sent.

ajax

```js
<script >

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-to-card").click(function() {
        var quantityq = $("#quantityq").val();
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var product__id = $("#product__id").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Addtocart.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                quantityq: quantityq,
                user: user,
                product__id: product__id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

```html
<input step="1" min="1" max="50" name="quantityq" id="quantityq" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" type="number">
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="72663">
<input type="hidden" name="product__id" id="product__id" value="4">
</div>
<button type="submit" id="add-to-card" class="btn sqaure_bt fll display-f">send</button>
```

Comment: So, have you used your browser's Developer Tools (particularly the Console and Network tools) to debug it and narrow down the issue? That should be step 1 before asking for help. We can't run it so we can't debug it for you, and we don't know what values you're sending (or not sending) in each case, or what the PHP code looks like. So it's a very incomplete picture for us...you need to fill in the gaps before we can help you. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mre] for more guidance. Also please take the [tour] to familiarise yourself with Stackoverflow in general. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you need the PHP code for the above code.. It's all about canceling the product_id in this part data: {
quantityq:quantityq,
product__id:product__id
                     },
But in the same part when I keep the product_id it won't work

Comment: Won't work _how_ though? What exact result do you get, and what did you expect? Do you get errors? Or unexpected outcome? Or what? Depending on what the problem is, it _might_ be related to how the PHP is dealing with the situation when the ID is or is not included in the request. Your description of the problem is not very clear, hence why we're asking for more info including debugging details, and code. Again, please read about how to create a [mre] for us to fully understand the situation. Thanks.

Comment: That's right..I'm sorry about this error, I found out that the error is in the php code (Addtocart.php). thanks bro..

Comment: No worries. If you think it would be useful to others, please add an Answer below showing how you solved it. P.S. Just a bit of friendly advice... not everyone here is a "bro". I would suggest using more neutral language to speak to people in future. I'm not offended but you never know who might be :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what issue you are facing, as you didn't post an example that shows the issue clearly.

But Rather than binding to click event of the button, you should bind to submit event of the form. This way, client-side form validation will work correctly and your JS code will be a lot smaller.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input step="1" min="1" max="50" name="quantityq" id="quantityq" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" type="number">
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="72663">
    <input type="hidden" name="product__id" id="product__id" value="4">
    <button type="submit" id="add-to-card" class="btn sqaure_bt fll display-f">send</button>
</form>



<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let postData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Addtocart.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: postData,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Will this code send all the inputs in the form? And with what name  will send it?

Comment: @Qutayba Yes, It will send all inputs in the form. It will use the name attribute of the input and send values of the input as those names. For example, your input names are quantityq, user and product__id, so you will get data in those elements in $_POST array.

Comment: I discovered the error.. Thanks for the alert, I have benefited from your code for other problems that appear to me.. Thank you